# Progress Dialog dismissing before activity finish drawing UI

Tags: android

Currently my application has two Activities and one activity with simple buttons and another activity is with a long UI.

So i want to open second activity from first activity and because it is looking frozen when starting activity directly, I had to use `AsyncTask` to open activity and show `ProgressDialog` while its loading. But the problem is `ProgressDialog` is just showing only for a moment and it is dismissing before second activity loads. Sometimes `ProgressDialog` is not showing.
Can anyone help me to fix the problem.

This is the `LoadingActivity` class that extends `AyncTask`

```
class LoadingActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        public LoadingActivity(InspectionSelectionActivity activity) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(InspectionSelectionActivity.this, TenWheelActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("selection", "value");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.isIndeterminate();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait.");
            dialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if (result){
                if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how i called it from button onclick listner

```
new LoadingActivity(InspectionSelectionActivity.this).execute();
```

Comment: So i want to open second activity from first activity and because it is looking frozen - What have you done in the second activity? `AsyncTask` just for an intent?

Comment: In Second Activity it loads a heavy UI with some compound views and lot other components. So it takes 2 or 3s to load. So i had used the AsyncTask. What would you suggest?

Comment: I don't think I can help without seeing the class. And I bet mostly that it's cuz of what you have done in the UI thread there.

Comment: That class has lot of things running in the main ui thread. How if i use a thread to open the activity?

Comment: You wont get to know when will the activity you're about to open via intent gets rendered completly. Calling intent will directly serves its purpose without any delay. Since you are running long process in second activity, do all these heavy work inside asynctask in second activity and remove asynctask from first activity, by doing so it will not have lagging while opening second activity from first activity. Show progressbar inside second activity untill the heavy work gets done in second activity. This will have better UX experience.

Comment: Actually Opening second activity freezing not because of the things done in class, it's because of the layout xml. it has lot of reused compound views in a scroll view. that is why it's get 2 or 3s to load.